# How to do fine-tuning in tensorflow with notop layers and define my own input image size

Tags: tensorflow, keras

There are many examples about how to do fine-tuning with tensorflow. Almost all these examples are try to resize our images to the specified size that the existing model needs. Like for example, 224×224 is the input size that vgg19 needs. However, in keras, we can change the input size by setting the include_top to false:

```py
base_model = VGG19(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(input_size, input_size, input_channels))
```

Then we do not have to fix the image size to be 224×224 anymore. Can we do such kind of fine-tuning by using official pre-trained models in tensorflow? I cannot find the solutions up till now, anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do this kind of fine-tuning. You would just have to ensure that you also fine-tune some of the first few layers (to account for changed input) of the original network in addition to the last few layers (to account for changed output).

I work with TensorFlow using Keras. If you are open to that, then there is a code snippet that shows the general fine-tuning flow here:

https://keras.io/applications/

Specifically, I had to write the following code to make it work for my case:

```
#img_width,img_height is the size of your new input, 3 is the number of channels
input_tensor = Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
base_model = 
keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False,weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor)
#instantiate whatever other layers you need
model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=predictions)
#predictions is the new logistic layer added to account for new classes
```

Hope this helps.